# What to use in place of union in above query i wrote or more optimize query then my given query without union and union all

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I am counting the birthdays , sales ,  order in all 12 months from customers table in SQL server like these

In Customers table birth_date ,sale_date, order_date are columns of the table

```
           select 1 as ranking,'Birthdays' as Type,[MONTH],TOTAL
              from ( select DATENAME(month, birth_date)   AS [MONTH],count(*) TOTAL
                     from customers 
                     group by DATENAME(month, birth_date)                                            
                   )x

    union

            select 2 as ranking,'sales' as Type,[MONTH],TOTAL
              from ( select DATENAME(month, sale_date)   AS [MONTH],count(*) TOTAL
                     from customers 
                     group by DATENAME(month, sale_date)                    
                   )x
    union

            select 3 as ranking,'Orders' as Type,[MONTH],TOTAL
             from ( select DATENAME(month, order_date)   AS [MONTH],count(*) TOTAL
                    from customers 
                    group by DATENAME(month, order_date)
                  )x
```

And the output is like these(just dummy data)

| ranking | Type | MONTH | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Birthdays | January | 12 |
| 1 | Birthdays | April | 6 |
| 1 | Birthdays | May | 10 |
| 2 | Sales | Febrary | 8 |
| 2 | Sales | April | 14 |
| 2 | Sales | May | 10 |
| 3 | Orders | June | 4 |
| 3 | Orders | July | 3 |
| 3 | Orders | October | 6 |
| 3 | Orders | December | 17 |

I want to find count of these all these three types without using `UNION` and `UNION ALL`, means I want these data by single query statement (or more optimize version of these query)

Comment: For performance questions, we need at a minimum: the tables and index definitions, and please share the execution plan via https://pastetheplan.com. This question is not answerable otherwise.

Comment: If you *can't* use `UNION ALL` might be able to use `UNPIVOT` or a `VALUES` table construct to unpivot the data; some sample data for expect results would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to create a CTE with all available `ranking` values ​​and use `CROSS APPLY` for it, as shown below.

```
WITH ranks(ranking) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) v(r)
)
SELECT 
    r.ranking,
    CASE WHEN r.ranking = 1 THEN 'Birthdays'
         WHEN r.ranking = 2 THEN 'Sales'
         WHEN r.ranking = 3 THEN 'Orders'
    END AS Type,
    DATENAME(month, CASE WHEN r.ranking = 1 THEN c.birth_date
                         WHEN r.ranking = 2 THEN c.sale_date
                         WHEN r.ranking = 3 THEN c.order_date
                    END) AS MONTH,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM customers  c
CROSS APPLY ranks r
GROUP BY r.ranking, 
         DATENAME(month, CASE WHEN r.ranking = 1 THEN c.birth_date
                              WHEN r.ranking = 2 THEN c.sale_date
                              WHEN r.ranking = 3 THEN c.order_date
                         END)
ORDER BY r.ranking, MONTH
```